# "Break even" price on call options is lower than current stock price?

Tags: options, call-options, quotes, robinhood

I am using the Robinhood app and see call options with breakeven prices below the current stock price.

Is there a reason why you wouldn't just buy this option and then sell it off immediately afterward?

Here is what I saw:

Current Price = $3.24

Strike Price = $3

Break Even = $3.12

Contract Price = $0.12

Why couldn't you buy this and then sell it immediately if your breakeven price is below the current stock price? Would you make the difference in profit?

Answer (score 6):

If those are the respective  real time quotes then yes, you could do a Discount Arbitrage (buy call, exercise call to acquire stock, and sell stock.  To avoid slippage, you'd buy a Synthetic Put via a Combo Order (buy the call and short the stock) and then exercise the call to close the position.

The reality of these 'free lunch' situations is that:

- you're probably not evaluating this based on the respective bid and ask prices, or
- you're looking at the last trade's price  (the quote is stale), or
- it's bad data